# How to prove that the cardinality of Collection of Borel subsets is equal to cardinality of real number?

Tags: measure-theory, cardinals, borel-sets

One way is obvious. Since every point set of R is a Borel set, so the Collection of Borel sets have at least the cardinality of R. I struggled to find an injection from The class of Borel subset to R?
Can anyone give me some ideas? (I did see some post mentioning concepts like cardinal, transfinite induction, but I have never learned those stuff. So if it is possible to proof without using those concepts it would be great. If it is necessary, please point me to a right direction of what to look at. Thanks!)

Comment: @bof Presumably what is meant is that the cardinality of the set of Borel subsets of $\mathbb R$ is $\mathfrak c$, not that each Borel set has that cardinality.

Comment: @bof Easier said than done, especially when there's a language barrier, which I suspect may be the case here.

Comment: Sorry for the mistakes, it is fixed now! Thank you so much for the help!